# Is it possible to remove database credentials in questions for real

Tags: discussion, feature-request

From time to time there's a new user who post a question (mostly in `[mysql]` or `[php]`) leaving their database credentials in the code.

I won't post any such question for some reason I can't quite explain, something like not aggravating matters, but I'm sure some of you know it happens.

The problem is that by editing the question we can hide the credentials from the first view, **but they are still accessible through the editing history.**

Is it possible to have a way to request a definitive erasing of content from the site? Could it be a type of comment in editing requesting for the reviewer to do a more permanent edit?

Or is it even relevant, maybe people just have to be careful, and too bad for them if they can't be?

**I would add** that this should be done in a timely fashion. Editing of course is the first mandatory step, but waiting for half a day before some SE employee reads a mail and does it can be troublesome, if I may

Comment: Flag the question using the Other option and describe the situation.  The mods can't do anything, but they can forward the request to SE team and they can physically wipe the earlier revision from the database.  Or you can click the "contact us" link in the footer of each page and email the SE team directly.

Comment: right, this is quite similar. sorry for not thinking of searching for exposed api keys :S

Comment: Before or after it has been crawled by archive.org and google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention, the moderators can ask an SE employee to remove the revisions containing private information.

One important part is that you should still **edit out the credentials**. This is something that has to happen anyway, the tool only deletes revisions. So there should be the last revision with the private parts edited out, this makes it a lot easier for the SE employees handling this.

Comment: How much time do you think that would take? We're considering presumably sensible information which can affect a lot of people is found by the wrong person. One could infect a whole server, putting down a great many sites at once.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier To be blunt, I don't have all that much sympathy with someone that puts the credentials to important servers on a public website. The blame lies entirely with the person publishing those private details. The time it takes to remove the revisions varies a lot, if an SE employee is online and can be reached immediately, it is usually rather quick. But it can also take a few hours until a mod sees it and can get someone from SE to remove the revisions.

Comment: A few hours? I flagged http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24152997/revisions on June 11.